# cron.service file not found

Tags: fedora, cron, services

My backup script works fine when executed manually; but nothing runs from crontab.
I am running Fedora 35 Workstation.

The crontab editor works:

```
$ crontab -e
```

The cron daemon is not running.  Each of these commands has no output:

```
$ pgrep cron
$ pgrep crond
$ pidof cron
$ pidof crond
```

My attempts to start cron:

```
$ whereis cron
cron: /usr/share/man/man8/cron.8.gz
$ whereis crond
crond: /usr/sbin/crond /usr/share/man/man8/crond.8.gz
$ sudo service cron start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start cron.service
Failed to start cron.service: Unit cron.service not found.
$ sudo systemctl start cron
Failed to start cron.service: Unit cron.service not found.
```

My attempts to use cronie instead of cron:

```
$ sudo dnf install cronie
Package cronie-1.5.7-3.fc35.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
$ sudo systemctl enable cronie.service
Failed to enable unit: Unit file cronie.service does not exist.
$ sudo systemctl start cronie.service
Failed to start cronie.service: Unit cronie.service not found.
```

Note also that anacron ("cronie.service") remains, if previously installed, during a Fedora system upgrade, but is NOT installed on, at least, Fedora Server 35, very surprisingly, when doing a fresh installation.

Comment: On my F35 XFCE VM, the `crond` service is installed and enabled by default; process is `/usr/sbin/crond -n`.

Comment: @ajgringo619 That worked!  How did you find the location of crond?

Comment: For future reference, the service is named `crond.service`. Docs: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f35/system-administrators-guide/monitoring-and-automation/Automating_System_Tasks/#sect-Cron-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron executed my backup script after using the crond location posted by ajgringo619:

```
$ ls -l /usr/sbin/crond 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 74448 Jul 21 15:05 /usr/sbin/crond
$ sudo /usr/sbin/crond start
$ pgrep cron
121692
```

Answer (score 2):

If this command is used:

```
# systemctl start crond.service
```

then the system will keep it up for you, even through reboots. Thus, you don't have to remember to do it!

Further, to get status, use:

```
# systemctl status crond.service
```

Finally, # of course means from the root account, so use sudo (or not) as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is probably using/calling resources with relative path and or shell environment context.

Cron runs its scripts without shell and without environment context.

Try running your script with user `nobody` :

```
  sudo -u nobody <your-scirpt-full-path>
```

Once your script is running with user `nobody` it may run in `cron`.

##### A common trick to inject current `bash` shell environment context to a script:

```
  sed -i "2i source $HOME/.bash_script" <your-scirpt-full-path>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu please use the following command

```
sudo service cron start
```